# встречаться vs. встречать

Tags: словоупотребление, глаголы

I'm looking at some example sentences with reflexive verbs and I've seen the following:

Я часто встречаюсь с друзьями

Can you also say?

Я часто встречаю друзей

If so, how would this change the meaning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those sentences are not equal in meaning.
**`Я часто встречаюсь с друзьями.`** The usual interpretation is about frequent meetings with existing friends. Potentially it can also mean *I often run across my [existing] friends.*
**`Я часто встречаю друзей.`** I feel the lack of context to interpret this definitely. But now my first interpretation is *I often run across my [existing] friends.* Also I can understand it as *I often meet/run across people who becomes my [new] friends.*
[**upd**] There’s one trick with the last interpretation: in it *‘friends’* can be *‘friends in the actual situation’*, not *permanent friends* as in other interpretations. *Friends* as opposed to *enemies* and synonymous to *allies*. [**/upd**]

`встречать` can also mean *to go to an airport or station to meet, welcome and assist someone with their arrival*.
[upd] However, with this meaning I’d rather say `Я часто езжу встречать друзей`.

Answer (score 5):

> Я часто встречаюсь с друзьями

I often make planned upon meetings with my friends. The friends also make effort to meet.

> Я часто встречаю друзей.

I often run across my friends. The meetings are not planned before. Alternatively it can mean that you often wait friends from plane/train/other trips.

Встретить means either run across or wait for arrival (from plane, train etc). Встречаться means to meet at a planned before meeting.

As a finger rule, встречаться means effort from the both sides, встретить means a random event or effort from only one side.

Comment: 'Встретить' can also mean 'accept', 'greet' (a guest) or 'celebrate'. Examples: 1. Вчера у меня в гостях были родители подруги. Я не ударил в грязь лицом и встретил их как полагается. 2. Бусы повесили, встали в хоровод, весело-весело встретим Новый год!

Comment: And 'встретиться' doesn't always mean arranged meetings, sometimes it's just passive counterpart for 'встретить': 'По пути сюда мне встретился только один велосипедист.' = 'По пути сюда я встретил только одного велосипедиста.'

Answer (score 1):

Встречаюсь с друзьями - it was planned.
Встречаю друзей - it happens by chance.

BTW keep in mind that if you say "Я встречаюсь с этой девушкой", it often means you date her.